# Firebase Auth Apple Sign In for Web "INVALID_CLIENT" error?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to implement Sign in with Apple on my React web application. I have created an AppID, Service ID with Sign in with Apple enabled. Created a Key, configured  and completed the required steps as outlined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple). However  I still get the following error response when signing in with apple. I have implemented both Facebook and Google signin with no issues.

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from https://appleid.apple.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://rideup-984a6.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n, contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], cookieList=[]}}",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from https://appleid.apple.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://rideup-984a6.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n, contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], cookieList=[]}}",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me solve this isssue.

Comment: We were able to resolve
Please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825346/apple-sign-in-getting-error-invalid-client-firebase-android/73825347#73825347

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this issue.

For me the error message "invalid_client" was a little bit misleading.

By following the docs of firebase on how to setup the apple signin method, you also need to create a private key in the apple developer console and paste it into your firebase settings.

What it fixed for me was, that I provided the private key Name instead of the key ID in the firebase settings.

You can find the Key ID, besides the name, in the detail view of the key, you created.

[Key ID in Firebase Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x71ke.png)