# Apple Sign in getting error "Invalid_client" firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

Everything we are done for Apple - SignIn

- In Firebase - we setup service-id, keyID, private key, Team ID
- In Android code - we did as same as document
  Still, we face problem of apple - sign in as Invalid client

Answer (score 0):

After long research we able to manage this problem

- In our case we add identifier instead of service id in firebase apple-login section
- Format of identifier example - co.myexampleapp.signinwithapple